# Add one spot to a value

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Its possible to book appointments in my app and I get the queue line value from this code to display for the users in the app:

```
Text = $"Spot {_Class.Slots.WaitList}";
```

What im trying to get here is to show the queue that person has. The issue is that the value im getting from that line is the value that says how many people there are in the line. So if a person books an appointment the value has to increase from e.g 2 to 3.

EDIT:

The value im getting from this code I get from the database:

```
Text = $"Spot {_Class.Slots.WaitList}";
```

The value is 1 (just an example) but i need the value to be +1 every time.

I tried to do this:

```
Text = $"Spot {_Class.Slots.WaitList + "1"}";
```

But it added 10 instead of 1.

Comment: Unclear what you are asking.

Comment: How about now? @EvZ

Answer (score 0):

What's the type of WaitList field/property?

I don't see a reason why this wouldn't work:

```
Text = $"Spot {_Class.Slots.WaitList + 1}";
```